# Mouse Avoidance mode Not Working When Set to `proteus`

Tags: mouse-pointer

Execute `emacs -q` and then evaluate

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(make-pointer-invisible nil)
 '(mouse-avoidance-mode 'proteus))
```

When *cursor* moves closer to *mouse-pointer*, an error is raised:

> Error running timer `mouse-avoidance-fancy`: (error "Sequence cannot be empty")

and *mouse-pointer* doesn't move away automatically.

Is this a bug?  If not, how to make it work as said in the [*manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-Avoidance.html)?

---

[image]

---

emacs-version: 29.0.91 & 30.0.50
system-configuration: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Comment: I tried it in Emacs 29.0.91 and had no issue.

Comment: @TristanRiehs: I tried v29.0.91 for MS-Windows just now.  Error.  I will post a GIF.

Comment: @TristanRiehs: updated

Comment: Same error on Emacs 28.2 on macOS. Smells like a bug.